# THEME_preprocess_field() not recognised in template.php

Tags: entities, hooks, theming

I'm using Drupal Bootstrap. Mail (password reset, user blocked etc..) from admin sends messages without preserving line breaks.

I tried [this](https://www.drupal.org/node/1095838) to fix this issue, but `THEME_preprocess_field(&$vars, $hook)` doesn't work for me.

Comment: Might be stating the obvious but did you change ```THEME_``` to your actual theme name?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Did you also clear the cache?

Comment: Yes, I cleared cache..

Answer (score 0):

Try with THEME_preprocess_field(&$variables, $hook), replace the **&$vars** with **&$variables**

Comment: Could you indicate why this would solve the problem?